# Save an object in wordpress database

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress

it is possibe to save an object in prefix_options in wordpress database like this one:

```
$arr_params = array( 'cat' => $display_category, 'product' => $single_post_ID );
```

Thanks

**edit:**

after make some changes, the code can't add an new array in exsisting array in the database:

```
$item= array(
            'name' => $name , 
            'prename' => $prename
             );
        print_r($item);

        $options = get_option( 'options' );

        if (empty($options['items'])) {
            $options['items']=array();
            add_option( 'options', $options );
            $options = get_option( 'options' );
            $options['items'] = array_push($options['items'], "$item");
            update_option( 'options', $options );
        }
        else{
            $options = get_option( 'options' );
            $options['items'] = array_push($options['items'], "$item");
            update_option( 'options', $options );
        }
```

Comment: Yes of course , you can.

Comment: Indeed. That's pretty much what get_option/update_option is for. What are you having a problem with?

Comment: @MattGibson, My real problem is I want store in the same field , like _arr_params, many opbjects with the same format of $arr_params.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can,

```
$arr_params = array( 'cat' => $display_category, 'product' => $single_post_ID );

if( get_option("_arr_params") === false ) {
    add_option("_arr_params", $arr_params);
}
else {
    // holds : array( 'cat' => $display_category, 'product' => $single_post_ID );
    $my_param = get_option("_arr_params");
}
```

According to Edit Part: `array_push()` on works to add one or more elements not the array, you can use `array_merge()` in place of it, or second option is i already used in below codes.

```
$options['wphyper_orders'][] = $order_detail;
```

helpful link : [get_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option)

Comment: Thanks @jogesh_pi, but to better understand my problem, I want store in the same field , like _arr_params, many opbjects with the same format of $arr_params.

Comment: @Boytun, why now make a mulit-dimentional array with different options? intead of creating new all the time?

Comment: yes nice idea, using **array_push**,  thanks @jogesh_pi

Comment: awsome, it works fine with **$options['items'][$key] = $item**, Thanks :)